# Using Gentoo portage to install programs to non-root location

Tags: gentoo

I am using Gentoo GNU/Linux on one of my home desktops and wanted to install all the self-emerged programs to /usr/local using portage (similar to FreeBSD port system), but was wondering:

1. Is it officially supported?
2. Does is it create any practical problem from a system admin point of view? (As I will be managing this system myself)

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with the `--prefix` argument to `emerge`.

```
emerge --prefix=/usr/local somepackage
```

This is equivalent to setting the `EPREFIX` environment variable prior to calling `emerge`.   If you start doing this you'll want to make sure `/usr/local/bin` is in your `PATH`.

Aside from that there shouldn't be any problems and from portages point of view there isn't a difference.  You also won't have any differences in administration.  Unmerging packages will still work the same.

There is one caveat to this -- dependencies brought in from the package you are emerging will also be installed into the new prefix.  If you really only want the packages you specifically emerged to be in /usr/local, you'll need to keep this in mind.

If your goal is just to keep track of what packages you've specifically requested to be installed, portage records this in your world file `/var/lib/portage/world`.